# React Back Button Loading Page From Browser Cache And Not Re-Calling API

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a react SPA that uses react-router. The app contains multiple different searches that call APIs. I would like the browser back button to load the previous search from cache rather than calling the API again.

The program outline looks like:

```
App
|
|-- Component
    |
    |- Search Component (uses push history)
    |- Results Component (uses componentDidMount & componentWillReceiveProps that call the API)
```

Comment: browser cache? you must be storing that stuff in state somewhere right?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably utilize [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) or [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) to save/cache previous searches.
On retrieving search result, save/cache the result in storage area mentioned above.

But be aware of following ups & downs.

- `localStorage` might be easier to implement, but harder to manage as
  you store plain text (you need to stringify if you are serializing an
  object).
- `IndexedDB` might be harder to implement, but can have a
  better structure.